# Find diameter and average shortest path length of a graph's giant component using igraph python

Tags: python, igraph

I want to calculate the average shortest path length and diameter of a graph's giant component. The files are represented in .mat format.Is there any built-in function to do so?

```
data = loadmat("filename.mat")
data=coo_matrix(data.get('A'))
graph= igraph.Graph(zip(data.row.tolist(), data.col.tolist()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Diameter of giant components

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149341/3350448), we can find the giant component with the following function.

```
def giant_component(graph):
    """Compute giant component.

    Returns:
        The giant component of `graph` as an `igraph.Graph`.

    """
    vc = graph.components()
    vc_sizes = vc.sizes()
    return vc.subgraph(vc_sizes.index(max(vc_sizes)))
```

Its diameter can be found as `giant_component(graph).diameter()`.

### Average shortest path

The [`Graph.shortest_paths`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#shortest_paths) function will return a matrix containing all shortest path lengths, of which you can then compute the average.

```
np.mean(graph.shortest_paths())
```